# Mango Secondary Live Tile issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a panorama application and I have successfully created secondary live tile with URI pointing to the desired xaml.cs. Now the xaml part which is separate from mainpage.xaml is of no use to me so what happens is when user goes to the secondary live tile, code from  desired.xaml.cs is seen by the user. But when he presses the back button, he goes to an empty page and then goes to homepage and  I am aware it is not possible to jump directly to home screen. So how do I solve this issue? If you are wondering how this works - try network dashboard for Windows phone. Quite similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't reproduce. When you are navigated from a Live Tile, and presses back, you'll exit the application, since there are no other pages in the navigation stack.

The Network Dashboard works the same way.

If you somehow managed to have other pages in your navigation-stack , consider removing them using [NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry.aspx)

Comment: That's what I initially thought as well. Now when I look at the app, I am puzzled. Isn't the custom page I created ( desired.xaml ) in the stack since the settings page is generated from the custom phone page, right? So going back from settings page takes me to a custom page (which is not needed) and then out of the stack i.e back to homescreen . I know it is a bit confusing. I hope you are able to understand my problem.

Comment: You need to simplify what you're doing greatly. Clearly it's related to how you handle navigation. Look into the `RemoveBackEntry` method.